# xsltproc (osx) "not a stylesheet, compilation error". but xml & xsl both work on online tool

Tags: xml, xslt

managed to get my xsl working at http://www.xmlper.com/ (great tool good recommendation from other stackoverflow comment).

but when I run the same (and now highly stripped down) xml & xsl on my mac os x command line I get "compilation error, Document is not a stylesheet"

Is it a version issue (output of xsltproc below)? i'm running latest mac (10.7) and latest xcode 4.2 (to ensure xml lib etc)?
i couldn't find anything about xsltproc not supporting xslt v2.0 (I've tried setting to v1.0 - no difference)
I did try and download other xslt processors (e.g. saxon) but got into old java versions and couldn't get the program to run.

hope someone has come across this and has solved it!
thanks

Ben

Input xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resultsfile>
  <planset>
    <voicemail_divert>
      <cost_over_plan>0</cost_over_plan>
      <this_txn_absolutely_cost_subtotal>0</this_txn_absolutely_cost_subtotal>
    </voicemail_divert>
  </planset>
</resultsfile>
```

xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="cost_over_plan">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
    <extracost_overplan_aspartoftotal>0</extracost_overplan_aspartoftotal>
    <extraqty_overplan_aspartoftotal>0</extraqty_overplan_aspartoftotal>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

error

```
$ xsltproc --debug --novalid --nonet f.xml add_extraqtyandcostfields.xsl 
compilation error: file f.xml line 2 element resultsfile
 xsltParseStylesheetProcess : document is not a stylesheet
```

version info

```
$ xsltproc -version
Using libxml 20703, libxslt 10124 and libexslt 813
xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20703, libxslt 10124 and libexslt 813
libxslt 10124 was compiled against libxml 20703
libexslt 813 was compiled against libxml 20703
```

Comment: Did you try swapping the position of `f.xml` and `add_extraqtyandcostfields.xsl` on the command line? (`xsltproc --debug --novalid --nonet add_extraqtyandcostfields.xsl f.xml`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented in the [manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xsltproc/), the stylesheet must preceed the XML file in xsltproc's arguments:

```
$ xsltproc --debug --novalid --nonet add_extraqtyandcostfields.xsl f.xml
```

should work.

Also, your xsltproc doesn't seem to support XSLT 2.0. Luckily, your stylesheet doesn't seem to require [new XSLT 2.0 features](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#changes). You can simply replace `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"` with `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"` to fix the problem.

Comment: @Ben No problem, everyone sometimes misses the obvious. One more thing: If this (or another) answer solves your problem, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 1):

**You have an XSLT 2.0 transformation, but the XSLT processor used (libxslt) only supports XSLT 1.0**.

One possible solution is to use an XSLT 1.0 transformation. This may require from minor to significant modifications, depending on what XSLT 2.0 features are used in the current transformation.

**I don't see even a single XSLT 2.0 feature in the provided XSLT code** -- therefore just changing the value of the `version` artttibute from `2.0` to `1.0` may eliminate the observed error.

Comment: In theory at least, it is not an error to say version="2.0" on a stylesheet submitted to an XSLT 1.0 processor. The standards define how the processor should behave in this case (run in forwards compatibility mode). It's known that this is not well implemented in many otherwise-conformant XSLT 1.0 processors; but I don't think that's the cause of the problem here. I think the problem is the command line syntax.

Comment: @Michael Kay: You are probably right -- this is why I said: "*may* eliminate the observed error".